# Google SMTP connection timed out

Tags: php, email, ssl, smtp, debian

I'm trying to send message using PHPMailer and google SMTP, but i got an error

> Connection: opening to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465, t=10, opt=array ( 'ssl' => array ( 'verify_peer' => false, 'verify_peer_name' => false, 'allow_self_signed' => true, ),)
> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110)
> SMTP connect() failed.

Mail sends fine from server on my local machine, but it doesnt work on my VPS (Debian 9). The port 465 is listening, this what i see when calling command

`netstat -pln -t`

> tcp  0   0 0.0.0.0:465     0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN 15436/master
>
> tcp6  0   0 :::465          :::*         LISTEN 15436/master

when im trying connect to google SMTP using telnet

```
telnet smtp.gmail.com 456
```

i got

> Trying 173.194.73.109...

and nothing happens then. Just empty command line with cursor, and i cant even exit telnet with ^], i have to restart my ssh connection. Same with port 587.

UPD: After a lot of time waiting i got telnet error

> Unable to connect to remote host: Network is unreachable

btw `ping 173.194.73.109` works fine

`telnet localhost 465` also works fine

Comment: Your VPS probably has outgoing connections to ports 465 and/or 587 block. Check your firewall settings.

Comment: I tried to open these ports by running `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 465 -j ACCEPT` and `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 465 -j ACCEPT` but it didnt held

Comment: And when im running `iptables -L` i got 
`ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:urd` on both input and output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if anyone is interested in solution, i just contacted to my support and asked if they have any limitations. They said that they doesn't have any, and they also resetted my SMTP, so it started to work fine.